# How to find the height of an odd regular *n*-gon?

Tags: geometry, limits, trigonometry, pi

When trying to calculate $\pi$ by polygon approximation, I found myself stuck when trying to get the height of an odd regular convex polygon.

Given that $\pi$ is a circle's circumference over its diameter.
A *n*-gon's number of sides divided by it's height would approximate $\pi$ as the number of sides goes to infinity.

Consider that the size of the *n*-gon's edge size is always one

- $S \rightarrow \infty$ (as the sides increase)
- $∆ \rightarrow O$ (the N-gon approaches a circle)
- $S/h \rightarrow π+$ (therefore $S/h$ approaches $\pi$)

I noted a pattern on the first few polygons 3, 5, 7

- For a 3-gon the height would be $\sin(60°)$ and $π ≈ 3.46 ≈ 3/\sin(60°)$
- For a 5-gon the height would be $\sin(36°) + \cos(18°)$ so 
  $π ≈ 3.24 ≈ 5/ (\sin(36°) + \cos(18°))$
- For a 7-gon the height would be ≈ $(\cos(64°)+\cos(38°)+\cos(25°))$

And so on...

As the number of sides increase we would approach $\pi$
and the height would be given by a sum of  trigonometric functions that contain numbers the sum to one interior angle of the same *n*-gon (note that all angles are equal)

eg:

- 2 sides - 60°
  h = sin(60)
- 3 sides - 54°
  h = sin(36) + cos(18)

Is there a more straight forward way to calculate the height of a *n*-gon that does not involve using $\pi$ in the function? Am I doing something wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: The standard approach to approximating $\pi$ using regular polygons uses the radius rather than the circumference. In terms of Vasya's answer, this means using either a leg of the triangle or the altitude of the triangle, not both. This means you don't have to do any case analysis about whether $n$ is odd or even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the height by using one triangle obtained by connecting two adjacent vertices and the circumcenter. Let the side of the polygon be $x$. Then we have an isosceles triangle with base $x$ and vertex angle equal to $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. The height to the base $h_1=\frac{x}{2} \cot (\frac{\pi}{n})$. The legs of the triangle will be the radius of circumcircle $R=\frac{x}{2} \csc\frac{\pi}{n}$.

The height of the polygon $h=h_1+R=\frac{x}{2} \csc\frac{\pi}{n}(1+\cos \frac{\pi}{n}) $